# ggplot melting and plotting of bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

How would I plot a bar chart showing the percentage within gender for each of the different levels of `var`

The data can be built as follows:

```
structure(list(var = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("-97:\nMultiple\nResponse", 
"-99:\nRefused", "1:\nDefinitely", "2:\nProbably", "3:\nProbably\nnot", 
"4:\nDefinitely\nnot"), class = "factor"), GENDER = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1: Male", "2: Female", "3: Unknown"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("var", 
"GENDER"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want the bars within `gender` to each add up to 100%

Answer (score 1):

Summarise the data to get percent by GENDER within each level of var. Below, I use `dplyr` to do that on the fly within the call the ggplot. I've called your data frame `dat`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

ggplot(dat %>% group_by(var, GENDER) %>%
         tally %>%
         mutate(pct=n/sum(n)), aes(var, pct, fill=GENDER)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format())
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** To ensure empty categories are included:

```
ggplot(dat %>% group_by(var, GENDER) %>%
         tally %>%
         mutate(pct=n/sum(n))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(var, pct, fill=GENDER)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format()) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```

Comment: This doesn't work quite well. The first level is missing and each of the response categories is adding up to 100%.

Comment: Some of the levels are missing because they are not present in the sample of data you provided. Regarding the bars summing to 100%, it seemed like your question was asking for the bars to sum to 100% for each value of var. If I misinterpreted, please explain how you want the data grouped.

Comment: Actually your workflow works really well, it just took me a minute. How would I change the order a bit so that all values of `var` are shown? Here is what I tried, but it omits some of the values of `var` that are not present:





ggplot(dat %>% group_by(GENDER, var) %>%
         tally %>%
         mutate(pct=n/sum(n)), aes(GENDER, pct, fill=var)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format())+
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)